# F# Cannot enumerate sequence generated by yield when using GetEnumerator

Tags: f#, sequence, enumeration, yield

The following example is based on a [snippet](http://www.fssnip.net/7Rr/title/Enumerating-function) that produces functions that allow enumerating sequence values one by one.

Here `printAreEqual ()` gives *true*, `print2 ()` gives *12345678910*, but `print1 ()` gives *0000000000*.

Why cannot the function returned by enumerate return the values of the sequence generated using yield?

---

```
open System.Linq

let enumerate (xs: seq<_>)  = 
    use en = xs.GetEnumerator()
    fun () ->
        en.MoveNext() |> ignore
        en.Current

let s1 = seq { for i in 1 .. 10 do yield i }
let s2 = seq { 1 .. 10 }

let f1 = s1 |> enumerate
let f2 = s2 |> enumerate

let printAreEqual () = Enumerable.SequenceEqual (s1, s2) |> printf "%b" // true
let print1 () = for i in 1 .. 10 do f1() |> printf "%i" // 0000000000
let print2 () = for i in 1 .. 10 do f2() |> printf "%i" // 12345678910
```

Comment: I've noticed that it works correctly (for the first run of `print1()` at least, when you change `use en` to `let en`. So it must be something to do with the disposing of the enumerator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `use en = ...` in the `enumerate` function is effectively doing this:

```
let enumerate (xs: seq<_>) = 
    let en = xs.GetEnumerator()
    let f =
        fun () ->
            en.MoveNext() |> ignore
            en.Current
    en.Dispose()
    f
```

You're always disposing of the enumerator before you start using it, so the behaviour is probably undefined in this situation and it doesn't matter why you get different results for two sequences with different implementations.

Fine-grained control of sequence enumeration is always tricky and it's hard to make helper functions for because of the mutable state.

Comment: Thanks @TheQuickBrownFox. I think you're most likely right. However I fail to understand why the enumerator would be disposed for one of the sequences but not the other depending on the implementation.

Comment: @TToi The enumerator is disposed for both sequences (some `Dispose()` method is run), but what should a disposed enumerator do when you try to enumerate from it? There is no answer to this question, and the result in both cases is likely just a coincidence arising from their implementation.